# Webscraper IMDB with pagination - saving first set of movies in next pages

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create an IMDB web scraper that will save some data from user ratings (later I want to implement some movie recommendation functions) to Excel. Every page has 100 movies displayed. If there are more than 100 movies ranked by user there is pagination. I have a loop that are saving the first 100 movies, then goes to the next page. And on the second page (movies 101-200) python is saving to Excel movies from the first page (1-100). If the user has more movies it still has the same issue.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from PIL import Image
import math
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.imdb.com/user/ur163997524/ratings"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
page = driver.get(url)
def nextButtonIsVisible():
    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lister-page-next')
    return len(buttons) > 0

def clickNextPage():
    print("Click NEXT button")
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lister-page-next').click()

movies = soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content")
movie_names = []
movie_actors = []
movie_years = []
user_rank = []
imdb_rank = []
movie_genre = []
pagnitation_range = ""

upperPages = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@id, 'lister-header-current-size')]").text
#print(upperPages)
moviesQuantity = int(upperPages)
pagesQuantity = moviesQuantity/100
pageCounter = math.ceil(pagesQuantity)
upperPages = int(upperPages)

movies = soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content")
while nextButtonIsVisible():
    for movie in movies:
        #movies = soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content")
        name = movie.find("a").text
        year = movie.find("span", class_="lister-item-year").text.strip("()")

        empty = ""
        for char in year:
            if char.isdigit():
                remaining_year = year[len(empty):]
                break
            empty += char

        actors = movie.find_all("a")[1:]
        actors = [actor.text for actor in actors]
        actors = actors[11:]
        imdbrank = movie.find('span', class_="ipl-rating-star__rating").get_text().strip()
        userRank = movie.find('div', class_="ipl-rating-star ipl-rating-star--other-user small").get_text().strip()
        genre = movie.find('span', class_="genre").get_text().strip()

        movie_names.append(name)
        movie_years.append(remaining_year)
        user_rank.append(userRank)
        imdb_rank.append(imdbrank)
        movie_genre.append(genre)
        movie_actors.append(", ".join(actors))
        data = {"Name": movie_names, "Genre": movie_genre, "Year": movie_years, "User rank": user_rank,
                "IMDB rank": imdb_rank, "Actors": movie_actors}
        print(movies)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_excel("movie_ratings.xlsx", index=False)
    def nextButtonIsVisible():
        buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lister-page-next')
        return len(buttons) > 0
    if nextButtonIsVisible():
        clickNextPage()
    else:
        break
df.to_excel("movie_ratings.xlsx", index=False)
```

I've tried to:

- locate inside ,,while,, loop another declaration movies = `soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content")`
- refresh the page before scrapping

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks It seems movies is never updated, but try to reduce modules, code to a minimum and also check your indents.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `selenium` needed to navigate the pages or to update the `soup`, example is focused on iterating the pages, so columns are limited tpo give an idea:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/user/ur163997524/ratings'
data = []

while True:

    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    for m in soup.find_all("div", class_="lister-item-content"):
        data.append({
            'title':m.a.text,
            'imdbrank': m.find('span', class_="ipl-rating-star__rating").get_text(strip=True)
        })

    if soup.select_one('.lister-page-next'):
        url = 'https://www.imdb.com'+soup.select_one('.lister-page-next').get('href')
    else:
        break

pd.DataFrame(data)#.to_excel("movie_ratings.xlsx", index=False)
```

Output:

|  | title | imdbrank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | The Terminal List - Die Abschussliste | 7.9 |
| 1 | Upload | 7.9 |
| ... |  |  |
| 316 | Stranger Things | 8.7 |
| 317 | The Mandalorian | 8.7 |